# My widgets do not save

Tags: widgets, register-sidebar

Every time when I save my widgets and navigate away from the page, my widgets are gone. The sidebar is completely emptied and no change will be saved.

I don't get any errors in the console or PHP log.

If I copy and save the widgets directly in the database under `widgets_text`, they will be shown but still I can't add or remove anything to the sidebar.

This only happens to my right sidebar, my left sidebar works fine while they are both registered in the same way. This is how I register my sidebars:

```
function my_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array (
        'name'          => 'Left sidebar',
        'id'            => 'left-sidebar',
        'description'   => 'Widgets dragged here will appear in the left sidebar.',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '',
        'after_title'   => ''
    ) );
    register_sidebar( array (
        'name'          => 'Right Sidebar',
        'id'            => 'right-sidebar',
        'description'   => 'Widgets placed here will appear on the right side of the website.',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget'  => '',
        'before_title'  => '',
        'after_title'   => ''
    ) );
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: There's a kludgey kludge involving changing to accessibility mode and saving, then switching back, but that doesn't explain why it solves it or what the root problem was to begin with

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have called a right hook to register your widgets.

You may call your widget through `dynamic_sidebar` function. Please see [full description](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dynamic_sidebar/).